# Crossings in $K_n$

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, graph-theory

I was wondering if we draw a $n$-regular $K_n$, is there a way to determine the crossings in this regular drawing? I know that the crossing number of $K_n$ has a crossing number of

$\frac{1}{4}\lfloor\frac{n}{2} \rfloor \lfloor \frac{n-1}{2} \rfloor \lfloor \frac{n-2}{2} \rfloor\lfloor \frac{n-3}{2} \rfloor$.

However this is not what I am looking for, since I am simply looking for the formula for number of crossings in a $n$-regular $K_n$.

Comment: What do you call "a regular $K_n$ " different drawing of $K_n$ will give you a different crossing number...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume a "regular $K_n$" is the drawing of the complete graph with the vertices equally spaced on a circle and the edges being straight lines connecting the vertices. For clarity, I define the crossing number as the number of pairs of edges which intersect at a point which is not an endpoint of both edges.

There is a nice trick to count the number of crossings in this nice circular drawing of $K_n$: every four vertices yields exactly one crossing, and vice versa. The proof is a simple picture. Four points on a circle span six line segments, with only one interior crossing. Thus the number of crossings for this drawing is $\binom{n}{4}$.

The formula you give is only a conjecture. The above drawing shows that the crossing number is at most $\binom{n}{4} \approx n^4/24$. The conjecture is that the true crossing number should be about $3/8$ times this.